# Delete certain folders from C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local via list of hostnames

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic

I have a snippet of code this site helped me with and I would like to alter to behave in a different way if possible?

Running the file on a local PC directly will scan the user profile folders, omits system profiles (to avoid unnecessary scanning) and deletes 2 specified folders from every users app data local folder.

What I need to do now is run it across the network where I have a list of hostnames and do it that way. The below is working running directly on the PC.

```
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    '"WMIc Path Win32_UserProfile Where (Special!='True') Get LocalPath"'
    ) Do For /F "Delims= " %%B In ("%%A") Do (
For %%I In (Folder1 Folder_2) Do (If Exist "%%B\AppData\Local\%%I\" (
    RMDIR "%%B\AppData\Local\%%I" /S /Q >nul 2>&1)
    )
)
```

I would like to change it to something like

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%~dp0hostnames.txt") do (
    For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
        '"WMIc Path Win32_UserProfile Where (Special!='True') Get LocalPath"'
        ) Do For /F "Delims= " %%B In ("%%A") Do (
    For %%I In (Folder1 Folder_2) Do (If Exist "\\%%B\C$\AppData\Local\%%I\" (
        RMDIR "\\%%B\C$\AppData\Local\%%I" /S /Q >nul 2>&1)
        )
    )
```

I have had a go but it's getting beyond my limited knowledge, I think I need delayedexpansion and also move on the variable letter further along the alphabet but I dont know in which direction :-

Any help appreciated ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is completely untested, but I'm assuming that you can utilise the `/Node` option of `WMIC`:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%Z In ("%~dp0hostnames.txt"
) Do For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1 Delims=" %%X In (`WMIC /Node:'%%~Z' Path^
 Win32_UserProfile Where "Special='False'" Get LocalPath`
) Do For /F "Delims=" %%Y In ("%%X") Do Call :Sub "%%~Z" %%Y
Exit/B

:Sub
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:\" %%V In ("%~2") Do For %%U In (Folder1 Folder_2
) Do If Exist "\\%~1\%%~V$\%%~W\AppData\Local\%%~U"^
 RD/S/Q "\\%~1\%%~V$\%%~W\AppData\Local\%%~U"
GoTo :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it in PowerShell. When you are confident that the correct directories will be removed, remove the `-WhatIf` switch from the `Remove-Item` command.

```
$dirlist = 'dir1', 'dir2'
$userdirs = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile -Filter "Special=$false").LocalPath

foreach ($ud in $userdirs) {
    foreach ($d in $dirlist) {
        if (Test-Path -Path "$ud\$d") {
            Remove-Item -Path "$ud\$d" -Recurse -WhatIf
        }
    }
}
```

Using `Invoke-Command` will allow you to run the script on all computers simultaneously. This assumes that the previous script was saved as `udscan.ps1`.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'host1', 'host2' -FilePath .\udscan.ps1
```